# Parallel-processing Apriori algorithm code?

Tags: multithreading, matlab, parallel-processing, weka, apriori

I am currently working on a data mining project using real transaction data. The store has 12657 different items. I have a total of 75,349 transaction records. (meaning my matrix is gigantic) I happen to be at a university with a state-of-the-art super computer. However, weka, my accustomed data-mining program does not allow multi-core processing. When I googled "apriori algorithm multi-core" I only get scholarly articles with no source code. I was hoping that someone might know where I could get my hands on some, or a better way to optimize association using this algorithm. Thanks :)

Comment: Your data is actually not so large (in sparse matrix representation) and you should be easily able to mine it with the standard APRIORI algorithm on a single core. I don't know if the Matlab implementation uses sparse matrices, the R and Python packages interface Borgelt's APRIORI implementation which uses the sparse representation.

Comment: The data set is large given the parameters I am loading into the algorithm. I do have it in sparse matrix representation and it helps to some degree. I not familiar with Matlab yet, nor R. I will look into the python implementation. The other problem I have encountered on Weka is not being able to set a large enough heap size. I have the heap set to 1028M and it keeps crashing. I look into it though.